# Unexplained thing during the travel from Delecordia to Kosridi

Tags: raymond-e-feist, riftwar-cycle

In the book [*Into a Dark Realm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_a_Dark_Realm) by Raymond E. Feist, chapter nineteen, the protagonists follow the Dasati Martuch from the Ipiliac world, Delecordia to one of the Dasati worlds, Kosridi. While the protagonists are about to leave *the space between moments*, that grey universe that is between space and time (or something loke that), Pug seems to notice something but cannot clearly see what it is:

> As Pug felt himself drawn into the Dasati world, something flickered past his field of vision. He tried to follow the movement, but he was physically yanked away from the void, and suddenly he was standing on a stone floor, in a room of black stone. He was on Kosridi.

I would like to know what "something" refers to in this excerpt. I thought that it could only refer to a visual artefact due to the fact that he is changing worlds, but more importance is given to that "something" in the following paragraph:

> Pug staggered a little when he let go of Nakor and Magnus's arms. 'There was ...' he started.
>   'What?' asked Nakor, his expression one of unusual concern.
>   'Something ...' said Pug. 'I'll speak of it later.'

Here again, we just know that Pug saw or felt "something", but nothing more. I kept that in mind during the read, but nowhere had I the feeling that he spoke of it. I read the two following volumes, *Wrath of a Mad God* and *Rides a Dread Legion*, but I don't have the feeling that this is talked of in any of those books. I know that Feist often writes about things that are dealt with in a following saga, but I would have expected something like that to get an explanation sooner.

What does this "something" refer to? Did I miss something important that could explain it?

Comment: I remember reading that and expecting it to come up again, but I don't recall it being spoken of either.

Comment: After having finished the whole series my best guess is that it's just yet another forward reference to the dread being omnipresent in both space and time.